# when I use export html data export in excel file then date not prefect which are below of 12 date

Tags: javascript

Example in date below in dd/mm/yyyy  02/03/2021 so which are date below 12 to automatically showing wrong as 03/02/2021

```
function ExportToExcel(type, fn, dl) {
            var elt = document.getElementById('tablexl1');
            var wb = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(elt, { sheet: "sheet1" });
            return dl ?
                XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: type, bookSST: true, type: 'base64' }) :
                XLSX.writeFile(wb, fn || ('CollectionReport.' + (type || 'xlsx')));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the **raw** option as **true**:

```
function ExportToExcel(type, fn, dl) {
            var elt = document.getElementById('tablexl1');
            var wb = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(elt, {raw:true, sheet: "sheet1" });
            return dl ?
                XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: type, bookSST: true, type: 'base64' }) :
                XLSX.writeFile(wb, fn || ('CollectionReport.' + (type || 'xlsx')));
        }
```